# How do you set the min and max y-axis bounds for sparklines in AgGrid?

Tags: ag-grid

I am making a table with multiple sparklines using AgGrid, and I want them all to have the same y-axis.

I'm happy to do this by hard-coding a min/max y-axis range, but I can't find any reference to this configuration in the AgGrid documentation.

Is this possible?